# how to merge two audio files parallely just like voice call(uplink + downlink) in media recoder. android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediarecorder

I have tried media recorder but in that specific audio source is only allowed. i was not able to add a normal audio file to it, ant way i foud many ways to combine audios back to back but non parallely

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaExtractor to pull samples out of each of the files and write to 2 separate audio tracks of a MediaMuxer. Depending on the player it will play them together. Alternatively, you'll need to use MediaExtractor and MediaCodec to extract the samples from both files, combine the samples (combine PCM samples), write to MediaCodec and take the encoded output and use MediaMuxer to write to an audio file.

Do you want to make an MP3? What are your inputs and outputs?